# Cannot resize Ubuntu GUI windows in Windows11 with WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

Before I upgraded to Windows 11 I used third party software to be able to run Ubuntu GUI windows in Windows 10. This worked quite well, but had some issues, so I updated to 11. I finally got emacs to start in a windowed mode. It works, but I cannot resize the window with a keyboard shortcut like native Windows applications (with the third party software I could do that).

Is there a way to make a Linux GUI window take up half the screen with a keyboard shortcut in W11?

(edited to add: resizing with the mouse works, and double clicking on the top to make it fit the screen also works, but that's not convenient)

Comment: Have you tried resizing the window with the mouse?

Comment: Yes, that works, and double clicking the top to make it full screen also works. But I routinely put one window on the right half and another on the left, and that is really annoying to do with the mouse.

Comment: Do Windows shortcuts work on these windows? See also [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/153196/create-keyboard-shortcuts-to-move-resize-windows-in-ubuntu) for doing it via the Linux distro.

Comment: @harrymc my problem is exactly that the windows shortcuts don't work. The window is part of windows, as in you can tab to it and minimize it in the normal way. I'm not yet at the point where I want to try wmctrl, unless someone has already gotten that to work.

Comment: For a real window, a program such the free [AquaSnap](https://www.nurgo-software.com/products/aquasnap) might help.

Comment: @harrymc Until someone has a better answer, I'm switching back to x410 as x server, but thanks for the suggestion. It's a bit of a disappointment that a 3rd party x server gives windows that work better than the new native solution. They respond quicker and can be resized with native Windows shortcuts.

Comment: Windows 11 has been released much too soon. It's really only a beta-stage software. I would suggest waiting a year before trying it again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move window to right on WSL not working](https://superuser.com/questions/1731130/move-window-to-right-on-wsl-not-working).  I know your question was first, but I didn't catch the "snap to side" behavior you were asking about at the time.