# Move window to right on WSL not working

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, wayland, ubuntu-22.04

I have Ubuntu 22.04 in WSL 2, and I installed `pycharm` and `xfce4-terminal` (I also checked with Nautilus) inside it.  For some reason I can't move any window to the right or left, neither with the mouse, by dragging the window to a corner, or with the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>.

I tried to install [gtile](https://github.com/gTile/gTile) Gnome extension, but I found that it is irrelevant because there is no X server; WSL 2 is running with Wayland.

To recreate the problem, just install Nautilus (`sudo apt install nautilus`) and then run it (`nautilus`) and try <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> or to drag it to one of the screen corners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Quick update: The release notes for the WSL 2.0.0 pre-release report that this works now.  I'll confirm and update the full answer soon.*

---

*Short Answer Workaround:*

Not on WSLg, but you can install a third-party X server on Windows, and windows launched via it will observe "snap-to" behavior.

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1580614/1210833) along with some additional detail in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1669770/1210833) for instructions.

*More explanation:*

A few things are going on here:

- First, unfortunately, snap-to just isn't supported in WSLg.  From the [WSLg architecture overview](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wslg-architecture/):

  > [WSLg] still uses server-side window movement and resizing, resulting in ... the inability to snap Linux windows on the edges of the monitors or to custom snap region. These annoy us too .

  That was from the "WSLg Preview", but it's still applicable today.  Also refer to and track [this Github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg/issues/22).

  I can imagine this will be a bit challenging to implement.  What really happens with any X/Wayland/RDP implementation in Windows is that the "canvas" on which the Linux GUI applications are running is a full-screen "rootless" window (no background).  As the architecture overview states, you are dragging the Nautilus window around *that* rootless window rather than around the Windows desktop.

  The same problem exists when running a third-party X server in fullscreen mode.   However, you can also run some third-party X servers in "multiple-windows" mode.  For instance, I just tested VcXsrv on Windows 10 (it will also work on Windows 11 with the appropriate `DISPLAY` setting), and `xterm`, at least, will snap to the left and right edges when running in "multiple-windows" mode.

However, Nautilus still will not, even though it's running as an X (rather than Wayland) application.

> I tried to install gtile gnome extension but I found that it is irrelevant because there is no X server, wsl-2 is running with wayland.

Well, there *is* an X server in WSLg, it's XWayland, running under Wayland.  So `xterm`, as an X-only app, is running on XWayland, and Nautilus detects that Wayland is available and runs in that mode.

I think the problem with qtile will be that it is a *Gnome extension*, not an app.  It depends on Gnome being the Desktop Manager.

Most every X-based "snap to" feature that I could find is dependent on the window/desktop manager, which means that they aren't going to work with WSLg's full-screen, rootless, Wayland/XWayland window.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I hoped that there will be a solution but it sounds like that solution is yet to be exists.